# Enforcing a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, relationship

[image]

I have this relationship where menu contains at least one menuitem. However, I was thinking if we create a menu, there will have no menuitem in it which violate the relation? How can we prevent it from a menu has 0 menuitem? Thanks

Comment: I'd consider [deferrable constraints](https://begriffs.com/posts/2017-08-27-deferrable-sql-constraints.html). That way you will be able to create an empty menu only if you add a menu item in the same transaction.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to do that. Some complicated ways are:

- Add a not nullable foreign key from `menu` to `menuitem` that points to one of the items associated with the menu.

  **Drawbacks:** redundancy that has to be maintained by each data modification, best with a trigger. Take care to handle deadlocks well.
- Add a trigger that ascertains that no data modification will result in an orphaned menu. To avoid race conditions, you'll have to use `SERIALIZABLE` transactions, which causes a performance hit.
- Add a counter to each menu that keeps track of the number of associated menu items with a trigger. Like the previous solution, that will only work reliably with `SERIALIZABLE` transactions.

Often is is the best choice *not* to enforce such a constraint in the database for performance reasons. After all, an empty menu is no catastrophe.

Answer (score 1):

Enforcing this constraint in the database is challenging.  The problem:

- You can't insert a menu because there are no menu items on that menu (your new condition).
- You can't insert a menu item because the menu does not exist (obvious from the current data model).

Instead, add a flag to the `menus` that gives information on whether there are any menu items.  Then only choose menus with items.  One method of maintaining this information is through triggers.  However, you could also just use a view:

```
create view v_menus as 
    select v.*
    from menus m
    where exists (select 1 from menuitems mi where mi.menu_id = m.menu_id);
```

Comment: The inserts are absolutely possible. Either by chaining CTEs or using deferrable constraints

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . You might want to answer the question.